# What Gems to be installed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, installation

I have an option to help setting up a server but at the moment I'm not 
sure about the gems to be installed. 
I want to ask you about the best gems you suggest.

I know they have FastCGI so multiple versions are supported.

The 2.3 Rails version list with ruby 1.8.7.:

actionmailer     2.3.8 
actionpack     2.3.8 
activerecord     2.3.8 
activeresource     2.3.8 
activesupport     2.3.8 
cgi_multipart_eof_fix     2.5.0 
daemons     1.1.0 
fastthread     1.0.7 
gem_plugin     0.2.3 
mongrel     1.1.5 
rack     1.1.0 
rails     2.3.8 
rake     0.8.7 
rubygems-update     1.4.2 
sqlite3-ruby     1.3.2

Do you accept it? 
What else? 
What versions for Rails 3.1 and 1.9.2 Ruby? 
What gems for multiple database support, I mean for MySQL or else.

Yours, 
Czakó, Előd

Comment: For MySQL you would install `mysql2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, usually you would just add gems as you need them, depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: I see m8. So you suggest to have them set up only the ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.2 and grant an access to be able to set for yourself? Actually I'm new in the Rails community, I have few experience. I'm trying to set up my first app actually. Never did before, so this is why I ask.

Comment: Thats OK, I get it. If you're looking at setting up your production server through your web host, then yes I would ask them for shell access, so you can install your own gems. If you're just looking for your development server, then just add them as you need them, yes.